# Bitbucket to FTP with pipeline and git-ftp

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I use **Bitbucket** for free repository.
I want upload files when I push on master branch.
I have an error when I push files on master:

> Uploading ...
>   fatal: Could not upload files., exiting...

**My pipeline config is:**

```
image: node:8.9.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          # - npm install
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git config git-ftp.user $SFTP_USERNAME
          - git config git-ftp.password $SFTP_PASSWORD
          - git config git-ftp.url sftp://$SFTP_HOST:22/$SFTP_FOLDER
          - git ftp init
```

My variables are defined in **Bitbucket**.

I am sure of the identifiers added in the variables. Is this a SFTP side issue? Do I need to add a configuration line to my server?

Comment: There's something wrong with your FTP upload. And that's about all the internet can diagnose for you without knowing what your variables are, where they're declared, etc. Maybe you misspelled `SFTP_HOST`? Or maybe the `SFTP_FOLDER` doesn't exist? Or maybe your password is wrong? Or maybe...

Comment: I am sure of the identifiers added in the variables. Is this a SFTP side issue? Do I need to add a configuration line to my server?

Comment: I have no idea... The error message conveys nothing. Maybe there are some logs with more detailed error messages?

Comment: I haven't more details :/

Comment: Does this help? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-Pipelines-Error-Log/qaq-p/107056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD sftp://$SFTP_HOST:22/$SFTP_FOLDER
```

Comment: I am the creator of the debian-git image and I would not recommend using it anymore. At the time I created it, there weren't a lot of alternatives. I don't have the time to maintain such an image, so `bitname/git` or `alpine/git` are great alternatives.